# How to loop through list of items and present it in a fixed amount of columns

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

I want to loop throw list of items and to present them in away that each row has 3 columns

Using this code,

```
<t:dataTable var="itemInfo" value="#{itemBean.itemList}">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{itemInfo.name}" />
    </h:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

I'm able to present it on one column, but how can I present it on 3 columns?

For example, if I have 9 items `A B C D E F G H I`, then it should look like this:

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use panelgrid with c:forEach like this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
  <c:forEach items="#{itemBean.itemList}”" var="itemInfo">
    <h:outputText value="${itemInfo.name}"/>
  </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

or you can use primefaces dataGrid or sth like that:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf

Answer (score 0):

Use panelgrid instead of datatable.

Regards

Comment: panelgrid won't help since I can't retrieve the element list from javabean using value binding as I'm doing here :  value=”#{itemBean.itemList}